# how to login using web api with angular js in mvc c#?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have created a small demo using web api with angularjs and MVC C#.
I want to add login module to this demo but i don't know how to use login method in this web api. I have tried this link but don't know how to call login method using "/TOKEN" api.

I have tried this link.
http://www.nakov.com/blog/2014/12/22/webapi-owin-identity-custom-login-service/?replytocom=384747#respond

Comment: please be more specific, can you say what you have tried and the outcome of that ?

Comment: try this link...http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/